# Python3, IOS, Flask, Sqlalchemy, Mysql with a column value = "Filled" breaks the ORM

Tags: ios, mysql, python-3.x, orm, flask-sqlalchemy

I cannot believe I am asking this question, but I am.

we have the set up as per the title.
We have a schema, with a table and a few columns. we have 400 rows and with 1 column having 3 string values: "open" , "cancelled", "Filled". This is very basic stuff.

Raw SQL in a Query Browser
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column in ("Open","Filled")
returns the result set.

The fun starts here:

sqlalchemy:
q=session.query(Table).filter(Table.Column == 'Filled')
when you run q.all(), the thing hangs and you need to restart the application.

q=session.query(Table).filter(Table.Column == 'Open')
returns the result set.
q=session.query(Table).filter(Table.Column == 'hfuefufwb')
will return an empty result set.

the application is also running on Windows and Python2 successfully.

if I run:
UPDATE table set column="xxx" where column="Filled";
then
q=session.query(Table).filter(Table.Column == 'xxx')
I get the correct result set. chnaging it back to "Filled", again breaks things.

"break" is defined as q.all() hanging.

the easiest solution is to rename "filled" to "baseball", but it would be interesting to hear any comments.

Is "Filled" a keyword buried in the ORM?

Comment: maybe you should submit  a bug report with sqlalchemy

Comment: we deleted the record then added exactly the same data and everything works. I might try to create a tiny mysql dump file where the problem is exhibited and do as you suggested.